# Uppercase testcase fails using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a test case as follows,

#1. If not in all caps do not give output. So I am writing an if statement where I am comparing if ab is not equal to amb then print none or print uppercase.

```
#Scenario 1
ab = "HELLO"
amb = ab.isupper()
if ab != amb:
    print()
else:
    print('yes upper')
```

Output expected here is printing yes upper but I always get none (as in the first print statement only gets printed). Not sure what mistake I am making. Please help

Comment: `isupper()` returns a boolean True/False not the string uppercase, the method that does that is named `upper()`

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was using isUpper and also not equal to sign. The below code fixed it.

```
ab = "hello"
amb = ab.upper()
print(amb)
if ab is amb:
    print('yes upper')
else:
    print()
```

Comment: For your own sanity, do *not* compare strings with `is` unless you know what you're doing. Use `==` instead. If you want to know why, read about string interning.